# How can I configure Spring to use the browser popup for authentication?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication

I have implemented custom security by extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` as below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
// Specify the authentication mechanisms that will allow user access to the site.
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
    builder.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("password").roles("ROLES_USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
}
}
```

As per many of the examples. However, when implemented in this way, I am thrown to a login page generated by Spring. I have found plenty of docs that detail how I can override this login page and provde a `.html` file of my own design, however, all I am really looking to do is supply credentials through the browser authentication popup.

My question is whether I can use the browser popup authentication to authenticate as per my code above (my actual code uses Kerberos in `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` but same general issue), and if I cannot, can some explain whether the browser authentication popup is reserved for a specific type of authentication or what exactly triggers it to pop up?

Comment: Do you mean the browser window that pops up when using Basic-Authentication?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove:

```
    .and()
    .formLogin()
```

from you configuration, then `.httpBasic()` will do the basic authentication with the browser popup

Comment: I really need some help. Can you please see what I am doing wrong in my code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076941/angular-4-0-spring-boot-spring-security-templateinputexception-error-resol